# Calling the Kura API methods?

Tags: java, kura

I am experimenting with the Kura API and would like to use some of the methods within the API in the near future.

For now, I am interested in the `SystemService` as I would like to create a simple API that returns the Kura version as an example. The custom API is working, the problem is however to use the `getKuraVersion()` method that actually returns the version.

Does someone have any idea how that can be done because I am unable to call the methods even though I declared SystemService?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Kura exposes services using the OSGi Declarative Services model. So, in order to use SystemService, you must obtain a reference to the service. There are many examples in the Kura repo of how to do this, but there is a test for the SystemService [1] that should be exactly what you need. A very good overview of OSGi Declarative Services can be found here [2].

[1] https://github.com/eclipse/kura/tree/develop/kura/test/org.eclipse.kura.core.system.test

[2] http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGiServices/article.html#osgi-services